# When i run maintenance plan that time showing in log viewer Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: database-administration

05/01/2021 23:15:14,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: ]
05/01/2021 23:15:14,Logon,Unknown,Error: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 8.

even i update SQL SERVER SP2-CU17

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU17) (KB5001092) - 13.0.5888.11 (X64)   Mar 19 2021 19:41:38   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 19042: )

Answer (score 0):

You can login Windows authentication, after that create job and run there is no a Login failed for user 'sa'.

don't use 'sa' user only use NT/windows authentication